# can i write 2 form tags in one .html file with action attribute to post on 2 different .jsp files?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have a login.html file which accepts the username and that is sent to login.jsp file that processes the data further. This username is sent via form tag. Code for the above is     and with this i am using the submit and reset buttons. Now there is an other file (search.jsp) that also needs the same username. Can i write 2 form tags in the same login.html file with one for login.jsp and the other for search.jsp ?

Comment: sure, you can do that. Why haven't you tried it? It's not that your machine will crash and burn...or is it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's absolutely fine. But you'd need to have two username fields, e.g.:

```
<form action="login.jsp">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit">
<input type="reset">
</form>

<form action="search.jsp">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="submit">
<input type="reset">
</form>
```

...but that shouldn't be a problem in terms of your UI design.

---

If you wanted to use a single username field, you *could* use a single form and change the `action` depending on which submit button is pressed using JavaScript:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="this.form.action = 'login.jsp'">
<input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="this.form.action = 'search.jsp'">
<input type="reset">
</form>
```

...but that requires that the user have JavaScript enabled. The vast majority of people do, but it's still worth flagging up.